# The requested URL was not found on this server (Magento)

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am using Magento ver 7. I have changed the server of my website with the same URL.

So, I export the database from old server and Imported the same database to new server. Apart from this I have also uploaded all the files to the new server.

I have also changed the database credentials in the /public_html/app/etc/local.xml file.

But now when I am open the URL, it shows an error that "Not Found, The requested URL /index.php/ was not found on this server."

I don't know why this is happening.

Comment: The above link works fine. Post the link which didnt work.

Answer (score 5):

It works for me.

> turn off url rewriting from magento admin configuration>web> Search
>   Engines Optimization > Use Web Server Rewrites > No

```
RewriteEngine  comment this line in In your .htaccess in the root of your installation
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried many solutions to resolve this issue.

One thing I did was I removed the `local.xml` file from the `app/etc` directory and reinstalled Magento. While reinstalling, in the third step I checked the two check boxes. One is skip base url and the other for url rewrites.

Then it worked like charm.

Answer (score 0):

I also got this problem when I was restoring a backup of the magento folder, The problem was that I copied the files with the wrong command:

```
cp -R /something/folder/* /folder
```

This command does recursive copying of all folder but ommits the files which start with ".", therefore the files which make a redirection like ".htaccess" where not copied.

Instead use:

```
cp -R /something/folder /folder
```