# Magento 2 static files not generated

Tags: php, apache, magento, magento2

Cloned Magento2 from github sources here : https://github.com/magento/magento2

The installation went fine. However some issues appeared when browser is downloading static files. Multiple files missing from:

```
pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/*
```

The installation went fine, AFAIK all static files were loaded.

**P.S.**

This might be somehow related but it seems that URL's are not rewritten correctly - throwing 404 page. I guess there is some strong correlation, but I can't see where exactly? Did some research (applied them) but without results

- [The requested URL was not found on this server (Magento)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22148252/the-requested-url-was-not-found-on-this-server-magento)
- [Magento - Currency - 404 Not Found - The requested URL /directory/currency/switch/currency/USD/ was not found on this server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25909247/magento-currency-404-not-found-the-requested-url-directory-currency-switc)
- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/22245/the-requested-url-customer-account-login-was-not-found-on-this-server

Comment: What server are you on? apache or nginx?

Comment: is your nginx config set same as suggested? https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/nginx.conf.sample

also if you have access to command line please try running `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` and check permissions again

Answer (score 0):

I was not having any luck with the "deploy" command. 
I turned on developer mode, which does not require the deployed static files, but still no go

Turns out there were other problems as well:
The Path names for the CSS and JS files were still looking for the files in a deployed directory under "pub/static"
Adding this setting in 'core_config_data' solved that: From [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30492838/installing-magento-2-does-not-deploy-the-pub-static-frontend-and-backend)

```
insert core_config_data (config_id, scope, scope_id, path, value) values (null, 'default', 0, 'dev/static/sign', 0);
```

After that issue was solved I still had problems. The .htaccess files have lines using the Apache 2.2 syntax.  I changed the main .htaccess to apaches 2.4 syntax but didn't realize there are many .htaccess files throughout the system. The one in the "pub" directory was preventing the css and js files from being accessed, because Apache gave up after not being able to parse .htaccess

In the .htaccess I simply put all occurances of these two lines as comments

```
    #order allow,deny
    #deny from all
```

It's just a demo Install on my local computer, so I'm not concerned. What one really needs are the Apace 2.4 versions for the .htaccess files.

Answer (score 0):

firstly you must set the file permissions

```
find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} +
find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} +
chown -R :www-data . # Ubuntu
chmod u+x bin/magento
```

Then clear the cache via command `php bin/magento clear:cache`

From now when you go to any page the necessary static files generated automatically.

Answer (score -1):

you must clear the folders in **pub/static** folder and than deploy the content

To delete the folders in pub/static folder

```
rm -rf pub/static/frontend/ pub/static/adminhtml/ pub/static/_requirejs/
```

than deploy

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: for nginx you can use this configuration https://github.com/magenx/Magento-nginx-config/blob/master/magento2/sites-available/magento2.conf